# How can I simulate a moving patch?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make a [Frogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frogger)-like game where the patches move around and the turtle can only move onto a safe patch. If I have a few patches that are red, how can I 'move' them around as if they were turtles? I currently have this, but it seems to move more than 1 patch at a time occasionally and as a result, some red patches will be destroyed if there are more than one that is red:

```
if pcolor = red
[ ask patch-at 0 1
  [ set pcolor red]
  set pcolor black ]
```

Comment: You may want to look at Wilensky's implementation: http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/1588#model_tabs_browse_info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ask the neighbor patch (left or right) to be painted red and the actual patch to be painted back to black or whatever the default color is.

For this you'll want to get the actual patch coordinates. Using `patch-at` asks the patch at `0,1` relative to the whole world.